How to calculate the correlation of coefficient between two different sets of NetCDF files?
I want to calculate the correlation of coefficient(CC) between two different sets of NetCDF files.
The first set of files are:
Dimensions:     (lat: 340, lon: 420, time: 366)
Coordinates:
  * time        (time) datetime64[ns] 2000-01-01 2000-01-02 ... 2000-12-31
  * lat         (lat) float64 -44.0 -43.9 -43.8 -43.7 ... -10.3 -10.2 -10.1
  * lon         (lon) float64 112.0 112.1 112.2 112.3 ... 153.7 153.8 153.9
Data variables:
    daily_rain  (time, lat, lon) float64 ...

The second set of files are:
Dimensions:        (lat: 601, lon: 500, time: 214)
Coordinates:
  * lat            (lat) float64 -60.05 -59.95 -59.85 ... -0.25 -0.15 -0.05
  * lon            (lon) float32 110.1 110.2 110.2 110.3 ... 159.8 159.9 159.9
  * time           (time) datetime64[ns] 2000-06-01 2000-06-02 ... 2000-12-31
Data variables:
    precipitation  (time, lon, lat) float32 ...

The spatial coverage and time coverage are different between the two sets of data. How can i calculate the CC between each grid? And save all the results into a new NetCDF file?
I have written this code, and the results i get is a bit odd.
    import os
    import numpy as np
    import xarray as xr
    from scipy.stats import pearsonr

    def calculate_metrics(silo_data, spp_data):
        cc = np.full(silo_data.shape[1:], np.nan)
        for i in range(silo_data.shape[1]):  # lat
        for j in range(silo_data.shape[2]):  # lon
            silo_values = silo_data[:, i, j]
            spp_values = spp_data[:, j, i]

            mask = ~np.isnan(silo_values) & ~np.isnan(spp_values)
            if np.sum(mask) > 0:
                cc[i, j] = pearsonr(silo_values[mask], spp_values[mask])[0]

    return cc

def save_to_netcdf(data, filename, lat, lon):
    ds = xr.Dataset(
        {
            'metric': (['lat', 'lon'], data)
        },
        coords={
            'lat': (['lat'], lat),
            'lon': (['lon'], lon)
        }
    )
    ds.to_netcdf(filename)

def main(silo_folder, spp_folder, output_folder):
    silo_files = [f for f in os.listdir(silo_folder) if f.endswith('.nc')]
    spp_files = [f for f in os.listdir(spp_folder) if f.endswith('.nc4')]

    silo_ds = xr.open_dataset(os.path.join(silo_folder, silo_files[0]))
    spp_ds = xr.open_dataset(os.path.join(spp_folder, spp_files[0]))

    common_time = np.intersect1d(silo_ds['time'].values, spp_ds['time'].values)
    silo_data = silo_ds['daily_rain'].sel(time=common_time).values
    spp_data = spp_ds['precipitation'].sel(time=common_time).values

    cc = calculate_metrics(silo_data, spp_data)



    lat = silo_ds['lat'].values
    lon = silo_ds['lon'].values

    save_to_netcdf(cc, os.path.join(output_folder, 'CC.nc'), lat, lon)

    


"the results i get is a bit odd." is not a good problem description [ask] and [mre]. My car is a bit odd. Can you help me?
